# How to get properties of an object stored in ArrayList using Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to print all student objects' properties(name, subject, registrationNo) stored in a ArrayList object.

student details are getting from a database and insert them into student objects.
Then these student objects are insert into the ArrayList.

Finally I want to print these student object properties one by one as follows.
[image: Question Summery]
Followings are my codes.

DBconn.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBconn {

    static Connection conn;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student_database", "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String RegistrationNo;
    private String course;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNo() {
        return RegistrationNo;
    }

    public void setRegistrationNo(String RegistrationNo) {
        this.RegistrationNo = RegistrationNo;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

}
```

StudentList.java

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentList {

    public static ArrayList getStudentList() {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student";

        try {
            Statement stm = DBconn.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Student student = new Student();

                student.setName(rs.getString(1));
                student.setCourse(rs.getString(2));
                student.setRegistrationNo(rs.getString(3));

                list.add(student);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

ViewStudent.java

```
public class ViewStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int size = StudentList.getStudentList().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(StudentList.getStudentList().get(i));
      //I want to get all student's name,subject and registrationNo 

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just use your getters. Something like `StudentList.getStudentList().get(i).getName()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply give Student a `public String toString()` method override, one that returns a String holding all key properties, and then this will work fine:

```
System.out.println(StudentList.getStudentList().get(i));
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `System.out.println(StudentList.getStudentList().get(i));`, you should access the student's properties and print it out.

```
Student s = (Student) StudentList.getStudentList().get(i);
System.out.println(s.getName());
System.out.println(s.getCourse());
System.out.println(s.getRegistrationNo());
```